# Server Mac address validiation

Tags: php, mysql, post, return

I am creating an application which verifies the client mac address , status , expiration date thorugh my server . I am new at php so I created this code to get a POST request to return the code in this way

```
status|Mac|EXP in milliseconds
102|2C59E54277E4|1516000210000
```

it should look for the mac on the table then get the  values combine them in the previous format and reply with the value above by posting the url

http://www.localhost.com/getLic.php?m=2C59E54277E4

```
<?php

// database connection parameters
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'app';
$db_pass = '123456';
$db_name = 'app';

// client information table
$clients_tbl_name = 'clients';
$mac_tbl_col = "mac";

$mac = $_POST['m'];

function ServerResponse($mac = '', $lang_id = 1033)
{
    if($mac == '')
        return $msg_sep . "Missing Mac Address !";

    $db_conn = @mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
    if(!$db_conn)
        {
            echo " Connection error !";
        }
    // select target database
    $db_selected = @mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_conn);
    if(!$db_selected)
        {
        // issue error response
        echo " Database Not Found ! ";
        }
    $rero = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT_WS('|', $status,$mac,$exp) FROM `". $clients_tbl_name ."` WHERE `". $mac ."` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($serial) . "'");
    return mysql_result($rero);
}
echo ServerResponse($mac);
  die();
}

?>
```

What is wrong with the code ?
it returns 500 Internal Server Error     !

Comment: What does the server's error log tell you? There should be an explanation about that error, otherwise debug it

Comment: I already uploaded the script to a site http://deaf-lovers.com/getLic.php?m=2C59E54277E4

Comment: What do you mean by that? Each server has an error log

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing `@` operator obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. You should display an error message for the user, log a problem, initiate some kind of retry, or all of these things in conjunction.

Comment: Actually I am so new at php I use C# and I am trying to follow the tutorial , I write the code on notepad++ an upload to the website , All I am asking is to modify the function so it would return the 3 values as mentioned above . Could you revise the code ? and edit it so that I understand it how should work ?

Comment: If you're using a tutorial and it's telling you to code like this I'm sorry to say that the tutorial is garbage and you should stop using it immediately. This is how PHP was written in the mid 1990s. Today there's better tools like PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Parse error.
There is one extra closing curly bracket after die(); which does not belong anywhere.

With 500 errors, take a look into the logfile (webserver + php error log).